# Does NJ law prohibit alcohol consumption in public parks?

Tags: new-jersey, alcohol

Does NJ law prohibit alcohol consumption in public parks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

TITLE 7 OF THE NEW JERSEY ADMINISTRATIVE CODE.

7:2-2.6 Alcoholic beverages prohibited

> A person shall not possess and/or consume alcoholic beverages on lands
>   and waters under the jurisdiction of the State Park Service except
>   where the sale, use or possession is specifically approved by the
>   Director of the Division of Parks and Forestry or the Assistant
>   Director of the Division for the State Park Service.

There is no statewide law governing non-state parks - like city and county parks for example. These entities are free to regulate as they see fit. For those rules you will need to inquire specifically.

Comment: That assumes that it is a State Park, though, or in the Service's jurisdiction.

Comment: Ahh. Yes of course. I'll either edit or delete.